# My libraries are not being loaded on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, config

Everything works fine locally.

In my application.rb :

```
module Maestra
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/MyLib/**/"]
```

Then I deploy, and in console `MyLib` is an undefined class.

So if I change my application.rb to :

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

*Then* `MyLib` is a known class but it has no namespaces nor methods.

My directories are set up as so :

```
+ Lib
  + MyLib
    MyLib.gemspec
    + lib
      common.rb
      my_custom_namespace.rb
```

So on my local I can very easily do : `MyLib::MyCustomNamespace`, but remotely, with the latter config in my application.rb, that namespace does not exist.

Comment: is the name of the file mylib.rb? Name of the file and module/class within should be the same to initalize on its own

Comment: Right? So if the only thing in my include was `["#{config.root}/lib/MyLib/**/"]` that should be enough? But it doesn't work on production. Maybe it has to do with my asset pipeline?

Comment: Hmm I just made it into a gem and now it works remotely.